# localhost refused to connect, after returning from paypal sandbox

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, paypal, laravel-5, vagrant

Testing with PayPal checkout with Selenium & chrome webdriver.

I have tried using another domain name, localhost and 127.0.0.1

It may be important to note i am running inside a Vagrant machine (homestead)

Also tests run manually work.
I believe the issue to be an environment variable
`PAYMENT_SANDBOX_PAYPAL_URL=http://localhost:8000/checkout/`, however that is confusing as from what i understand there should be no difference when running automated tests with a webdriver.

Is this a networking issue with vagrant and my host? how would i diagnose this?

[image]

I understand this is a pretty specific question to the mentioned setup, however i think other new selenium users like myself will find it useful, especially when using codeception and laravel.

Perhaps it has something to do with whitelisting ip's?
Here is the current command.

```
java -jar vendor/se/selenium-server-standalone/bin/selenium-server-standalonjar -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin="/usr/bin/google-chrome" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="vendor/bin/chromedriver" -Dwebdriver.chrome.options="--whitelisted-ips=173.0.82.77,127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: try binding it to 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: are you able to telnet ip and port

Comment: Are you running a server on vagrant that is running on port 8080?  Is the selenium server also running on the vagrant machine?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess chrome is running with different profile when launched manually (when it is able to load) and when launched through webdriver. WebDriver launches the browser in a different profile which may be very different than default profile which may include some settings related to proxy/networking.

From https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

By default, ChromeDriver will create a new temporary profile for each session. At times you may want to set special preferences or just use a custom profile altogether. If the former, you can use the 'chrome.prefs' capability (described later below) to specify preferences that will be applied after Chrome starts. If the latter, you can use the user-data-dir Chrome command-line switch to tell Chrome which profile to use:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
```

You can create your own custom profile by just running Chrome (on the command-line or through ChromeDriver) with the user-data-dir switch set to some new directory. If the path doesn't exist, Chrome will create a new profile in the specified location. You can then modify the profile settings as desired, and ChromeDriver can use the profile in the future. Open chrome://version in the browser to see what profile Chrome is using.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that PayPal Sandbox URL should be a local URL, not accessible from outside of your box?

Please provide more details! What web framework/web server do you use? What are libraries you used to get PayPal working.

I think, if the behavior differ when running Selenium, it is an issue completely related to WebDriver settings, or it's work together with Vagrant.